# Is there any word for the opposite of a "bug" in programming?

Tags: antonyms, programming

A "bug" is essentially when a program fails to function as expected/desired.

What I'm looking for is a word for the opposite of that - a function that is desired but isn't supposed to be working yet unexpectedly starts working. As an example, I'm developing an iOS app at the moment. It includes notifications upon certain events. We didn't think anyone had deployed our push notification server yet and notifications hadn't been tested at all, but in the course of testing other things, notifications somehow started showing up.

I feel like this is a feeling familiar to all programmers. Is there a word?

Comment: A lucky or coincidental feature is what I usually call them.

Comment: I thought you actually wanted an antonym to "insect"! Oh, and I'd call that "sheer dumb luck".

Comment: Miracle.  Psychotic imagining.

Comment: Chris V, what about *unbug*?

Comment: If there isn't a word I was thinking about "butterfly". It keeps the insect motif and the idea is that the feature is presumed to be a cocooned grub still but suddenly bursts out flapping its wings.

Comment: The opposite of a bug should be a gub.

Comment: Though feature is the first thta comes to mind, but wouldn't it be a simple "Fix"

Comment: I think you've asked two different questions: a word for the opposite of a bug, which would be something that works as expected; and surprise when work has already been done that you were unaware of. I guess you should split into two questions, or clarify to leave one.

Comment: Something too rare and magical to have a name

Comment: @ssdecontrol usually we just call that a unicorn

Comment: It's called a "bug". Just because it works, that doesn't make it correct. Unless you understand why, and can be more certain that it will work under other conditions, your code isn't done yet.

Comment: Call it a *flower*.

Comment: This is a really good question, and I'm not really satisfied with the current answers, as they fail to capture the actual feeling. Anyhow, I was instantly reminded of the [magic switch story](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html), which I feel compelled to share. Maybe 'magic'? As in: *Due to inexplicable magic, the push notifications suddenly started working*

Comment: I tend to describe this as getting a feature for free (no effort) but if you didn't intend for it to happen, it's still a bug.

Comment: If it's not a bug, [then it's a feature](http://carthik.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/feature-bug.jpg).

Comment: Anyone didn't do it, [Nobody did](http://www.columbia.edu/~sss31/rainbow/whose.job.html).

Comment: **undocumented feature**.

Comment: There was an entry in Jargon Watch in Wired Magazine years ago that describes this situation : JOOTT - just one of those things. It is defined as an unexplained problem that resolves itself over time.

Comment: A professor I had in college would refer to this as a "fortunate combination of errors." Not very succinct, perhaps, but a nice little phrase.

Comment: **unsupported feature**

Comment: ... a surprise?

Comment: I'm not sure how this corner of StackExchange works. I like "ladybird/ladybug" the best but am I supposed to pick as an answer the answer I like or the most "correct" answer?

Answer (score 121):

To my mind the behaviour you describe **is still a bug**. A bug is what you have when Actual Results differ from Expected Results - and this is exactly what you have here.

Comment: Ladybug perhaps

Comment: I agree. Technically this is still a bug, albeit a pleasant one.

Comment: Yes. If you don't know why it works now, you won't be able to fix it when it stops working.

Comment: Let's say I am new `python` programmer, and I want to iterate over `keys` of a dictionary, so I intend to do `[k for k in my_dict.keys()]` but I accidentally forget `.keys()` of course the code would still work, but I would not expect it too, and I would be surprised that it works. Would you say that I have a bug?

Comment: Still a bug.  A beneficial bug, perhaps, but a bug.

Comment: @cellik I like your suggestion but I'd have to call it a _ladybird_ in my dialect! It's still a bug but a pretty one and it's considered special when one lands on you!

Comment: While it's accurate that it's still a bug, I think that's missing the point. A heisenbug is also "just a bug" but the word was coined to describe some more specific common experience. In fact, a bug is itself "just a malfunction" if you want to get ever more general.

I like ladybug/ladybird, that's along the same lines as butterfly.

Comment: @Akavall Yes, until you realize how it works.

Comment: @Akavall: As you expect to be iterating over the keys, your code is doing something different than you expect and hence it is a bug. The mere fact that it does not visibly fail (e.g. due to a compiler error or runtime exception) does not mean it "works".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, in my example iterating over dictionary object in the pythonic way of iterating over keys, so not having `.keys()` is actually better.  That's why I am reluctant calling this a bug.

Answer (score 88):

Feature.
There is a programming joke, '**It's not a bug, it's a feature**' and 'If you can not fix a bug, try to prove it's a feature'

But grammatically, 'bug' is a slang for 'error', and the opposite for 'error' in programming code is 'validity', and debugging software naming is 'debugger' or 'validation software'.

The error messages may state 'Invalid code', 'Invalid operation', 'Invalid usage'

What you described is '**undocumented features**' or '**undocumented behavior**', which is still a bug.

Note Mathijs Segers' comment, a very good suggestion, software developers often announce 'bug fixes' in every new version or subversion. A '**fix**' is a valid opposite for 'bug'

Comment: And being undocumented, it may change at any moment so shouldn't be relied upon... unless you can convince the developers to make it official.  This isn't really an English question, though.

Comment: They are not the jokes at all. The joke is "It's not a bug, it's a feature!".

Comment: The way tech writers see it, the only features or functions that need to be explained to users are the ones that do not behave the way you expect. This includes bugs as well as other counter-intuitive program behavior. And we document what the humans must avoid because the program does not prevent them from doing it. There are always gaps in the _input edits_. These are neither bugs nor features; I call them _infelicities_.

Comment: "Undocumented feature" is a joking euphemism for a bug... which is what this is. Unexpected behavior (if it's unexpected to the program's designers/developers, at least) is always a bug, regardless of whether any given result of said bug may be desirable or not.

Comment: reirab, yes, 'undocumented feature' is joke, but it exactly matches what the question describes, '... a function that is desired but isn't supposed to be working yet unexpectedly starts working'. Everything undocumented but existent is a bug, but some bugs behave like features, they look like features.

Comment: [Its not a bug, Its a Feature](https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/a/a3/Not_A_Bug_-_Feature.jpg/212px-Not_A_Bug_-_Feature.jpg)

Comment: WernerCD, right, edited. The VW is funny, but I am not sure it is proper in language usage discussion

Comment: "... the only features or functions that need to be explained to users are the ones that do not behave the way you expect". So, basically, explain *everything*, then.

Comment: "bug" is not "slang for error", "bug" is a historical term derived from the process of fixing old vacuum tube based computers from yesteryear, where a moth or similar would find its way into the computer causing a short (and an error in programming). Thus the term "debugging" was born, and still, today, we refer to programming errors as "bugs". Often users refer to things as bugs which are not, such as feature changes, or unexpected behaviors which are not bugs (but were otherwise unintended.) This is also why we have a running joke about certain bugs being features. </history-lesson>

Comment: Shaun Wilson, a great point about the history of the term. Still I am not sure if it is a term or a slang word for this reason: the term is something that is singular, singularity is a property of a term. Something other than a term may be slang. In case of a live bug in vacuum tube it was the term describing the object literally. In case of computer bug, error is implied.

Comment: i see. the difference between this and slang is that "bug" has a formal definition, one that it is taught to students in higher education, based on that definition the closest antonyms of "software bug" would be a "software fix" (or simply a "fix") and a "software feature" (or simply a "feature") -- i.e. rather than an **undesired behavior**, a **desired one**. synonyms for "bug" include: fault, error, defect, flaw; it's worth noting that no educational resource seems to list any antonyms for "bug" as the term relates to software

Comment: @ShaunWilson: the exact [historical origin of "bug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug#History) isn't certain, but it probably comes from "bugbear" or "bugaboo", and was in usage by the 1870s, well before vacuum tubes or inanimate computers. Literal bugs in a machine were far too uncommon to inspire terminology; when a moth was found in a relay, it was noteworthy enough to be logged and then talked about in computing folklore.

Comment: "Bug" is usually classified as "jargon", which is in the realm of "technical/trade slang" (there isn't a hard taxonomy for these things).

Answer (score 24):

Most appropriate expression seems to be **"unintended feature"**.

A bug is unintended, and is bad for users.
A **feature** is good for users, but, in this case, it was **unintended**.

Web Search also throws a lot of results for this expression, so it seems to be **widely accepted**.

After some more thoughts on this, I have this grid:

```
|      -        | unintended | intended    |
| bad for user  |     bug    | restriction |
| good for user |      ?     | feature     |
```

While looking row-wise (viewpoint : "It is a feature"), we can fill in with **"unintended feature"**.
While looking column-wise (viewpoint : "It is a bug"), we can fill in with **"beneficial bug"**.

Completing the analysis of the grid : It is partially a feature and partially a bug, so I might add the answers by @Nanne , **featurebug** & **bugfeature**.

A comment about the **restriction** : When software has intentionally disabled features (User : "I can draw pictures, but can not save them"; Developer : "You have to buy a license for the software, and this **restriction** will be removed") and makes it bad for the user.

Comment: Although in actual use, beware that "unintended feature" is also a joking euphemism for "bug". Less so than "undocumented feature", but still could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Very closely related, we've used "accidental feature" a few times when talking to our product owner

Comment: @Izkata, I like "accidental feature" too. Some more variations are "fortuitous feature" & "inadvertent feature" & "unintentional feature".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Also, some people are saying it's still a bug, but I think that's if and only if the requirements particularly held that it should not have been in there.  The OP's description makes it sound like a grey area in this case.

Answer (score 16):

The discovery is a **serendipity** - meaning the fact of finding pleasant or useful things by chance.

Answer (score 9):

**[Glitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch)**: the exploitable kind (hacks), not the incorrectly written kind (bugs). **From my [GAMING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitching) experience**, a programing **bug** *doesn't* let me do something I should be able to. A **glitch** *lets* me do something I want, that I shouldn't be able to.

Bug, bad; glitch, good.

> An inexplicable problem or condition happening in a system.
>   *A glitch in the code gave Bob twenty-six free months of AOL.* -[urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Glitch)

Generally, a bug is upsetting to both parties, while a glitch is good for the unscrupulous *player* (me), it is not good for the *programer* (you), whose job it is to fix it.

To Bob, it's a glitch; to AOL, it's a bug. 'Features' are in the eye of the beholder.

There *is* a <strike>bug</strike> *inexplicable condition* in your code; it just happens to be "desirable" and you should have "expected" that there would be some errors.

A bug becomes a glitch once someone can repeatedly exploit the vulnerability: [GTA Money Glitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=gta%20money%20glitch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Your glitch will revert to a bug when you discover that it had broken functionality, elsewhere.

Comment: To me a glitch means something unintended but that doesn't prevent the program functioning (as a bug does). Glitch doesn't carry positive connotations for me.

Comment: I think a glitch is a one-off unexplainable event (positive or negative). From the description, this is reproducible.

Comment: [How do I do the Sword Familiar Glitch?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/196885-castlevania-symphony-of-the-night/answers/260488-how-do-i-do-the-sword-familiar-glitch)

Comment: Dictionary meaning of "glitch" : A **fault or defect** in a computer program, system, or machine. Does not seem appropriate here.

Comment: I think, "glitch" generally has negative implications, while the Urban Dictionary Example is an exception. Even if we change that Example to "A **bug** in the code gave Bob . . . " , the meaning is still the same. Many Examples of glitches are available here {{ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch }} , where most of the cases have negative implications.

Comment: TFD's definition of *glitch* is lacking. Anyone who doesn't think that at least some glitches are useful, isn't a user; they're an employee.

Comment: As @starsplusplus, I use _bug_ for the reproducible ones, and _glitch_ for the others.

Comment: Mazura's definition is indeed one fairly common (at least in-community) use of the term "glitch", though perhaps a newer usage of the term. As a programmer the term would be negative and mean "bug" to me, but as a user I would interpret the term "glitch" as either an undocumented (and positive) feature *or* as a system flaw depending on context (the situation and who is speaking). To *younger* gamers this term nearly always has the positive connotation, to business software authors/users it is nearly always negative.

Comment: I also agree with @ChrisV - A glitch is an unintended hiccup that does not cause the program to stop functioning. I once had a laptop that when removed from an external display, would flash it's screen (go blank for a moment then come back) once every 10 minutes or so until I rebooted it. It only occurred when I had plugged in an external screen, and subsequently removed it at a later point. Was this a positive glitch? No. Did it stop the laptop from functioning? No. Was it annoying? A little.

Answer (score 9):

We call this "working by accident". Also applies to any untested code--sure, it happens to work now, but there's no guarantee that it will work in the future.

Answer (score 6):

The jargon term [*misbug*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/misbug.html) describes "[a]n unintended property of a program that turns out to be useful; something that should have been a bug but turns out to be a feature."

A program, feature or code path that simply works without hassle [*wins*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/W/win.html).  If the win is sufficiently significant or serendipitous it might even be a [*big win*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/big-win.html).

Comment: Ah, the Jargon File...  Can't beat it!  Bogons, microfortnights, point-and-drool interfaces :)

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answers calling it a bug, we call this a "**featurebug**". Technically it shouldn't do what it does, but currently it *is* doing what it does obvioulsy, and people use it.

Examples would be closer to things like: if you click here it not only does "action x" but it also redirects you to this other page. Even thoug it was not intended to dot his, it's seen as a feature by the user, as we need to go there anyway. So that's a **featurebug**.

(If you make a feature that nobody wanted and that actually makes things worse, but does work as you intended, that would be a "bugfeature" obviously, but that's a whole different beast)

Comment: a great name; not a well-known nor widely used one, bordering on neologism - but a brilliantly spot-on, with a definite +1 in my book!

Answer (score 5):

We call these latent bugs. If it works when it should not, it will transition to not working at the most inconvenient time.

Answer (score 4):

I really like CrisV's suggestion **butterfly**. I think I will incorporate it to my day-to-day speech :)

Looks like there is not a short word for this lucky feature. The closest I have seen in the comments and answers is **unintended feature**.

But words are created by constant use. And in this case, I think we need something nice to show this concept.

Answer (score 4):

They're usually called "easter eggs"; they're peculiar "treats" that programmers add intentionally or otherwise.  Usually they're intentional but "neat" features are sometimes accidental.

Answer (score 3):

Notifications started showing up *automagically*.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm developing an iOS app at the moment. It includes notifications
>   upon certain events. **We didn't think anyone had deployed our push
>   notification server yet** and notifications hadn't been tested at all,
>   but in the course of testing other things, **notifications somehow
>   started showing up**.
>
> I feel like this is a feeling familiar to all programmers.

The word you want is **magic** or **magical**. The key part is that you got some desirable functionality but you don't understand why or how it works. So in that situation you might say "I didn't think we implemented this feature, but somehow it **magically** started working!"

Some other people pointed out that this is still a "bug" in terms of software development and that part is correct. You do not actually want "magical" functionality in your product. That's because there's no guarantee that the "magic" will continue to the next release, for example. And a "magic" feature probably is not testable either. You also said you didn't test it.

Notice that this phrase is distinct from saying "It works **as if by magic**." When you use this formulation, you know that it is not, in fact, magical, but that the feature you are pointing to is impressive enough to be touted as magical even though it isn't.

Another commonly used but distinct phrase in software is "automagically". However, **automagically** in software refers to a deliberate feature that automates a task "as if by magic". In other words, it automates a task in a way that is impressive enough to seem like magic, but it is nonetheless a well understood functionality by its implementors and is therefore not true magic.

Answer (score 3):

I would call this a **happy accident**.

> a pleasant situation or event that is not planned or intended ([Idiom Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+happy+accident))
>
> when something unexpectedly good comes from what would otherwise be considered a mishap ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=happy+accident))

The latter is not a perfect fit, but it *could* have been a mishap if someone had turned on the feature before you expected and it *didn't* work.

It doesn't sound like a "bug", because it was working as intended; you just didn't realize someone had turned it on.  That would be like saying:  "I developed this really great website but I didn't think anyone had turned the web server on yet.  Then I discovered someone had!" Would you call the website a bug?  I think not.

And "undocumented feature" would only fit if it were, in fact, undocumented.  If the notification feature was fully documented and you just didn't realize anyone had turned it on, that's not really the same thing.

Comment: "Happy accident" is accurate, but so is "malfunction" instead of "bug". "Happy accident" seems a bit too general.

Answer (score 2):

It's a stretch, but you might consider **inadvertent Easter Egg**. Ordinarily, an Easter Egg is a feature that is not obvious, but can be stumbled upon if you know where to look. In the case you describe, the notification process started working even though, to the best of your knowledge, it should not have been. These Easter Eggs (the notifications) were inadvertently caused by the app programmers - hence the name.

Comment: That was my first thought, easter egg.

Comment: An [Easter egg](https://bitbucket.org/mevi-ltd/lightgeist.tempest/wiki/specification/alonso/camera-management) is something intentionally programmed as a secret for the users to find (hence the name). I think it's stretching it a bit too much to use it to describe something that nobody hid and the developers themselves "found" by accident.

Comment: Which is why I used the term "inadvertent".

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast an "inadvertent Easter Egg" makes no sense. Being inadvertent automatically precludes it from being an easter egg.

Comment: The first line of [Wikipedia Easter egg (media)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29): "An Easter egg is an **intentional** inside joke, hidden message, or feature in a work such as a computer program, video game, movie, book, or crossword puzzle."

Comment: Right. So an inadvertent Easter Egg is ""An inadvertently hidden message, or feature in a work such as a computer program, video game, movie, book, or crossword puzzle."  Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

“[The Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html)” lists a few possibilities:

> [**black magic:** n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/black-magic.html):
>   A technique that works, though nobody really understands why.

> [**feature:** n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/feature.html)
>   (definition #3):
>   A surprising property or behavior…

> [**misbug:** n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/misbug.html):
>   An unintended property of a program that turns out to be useful;
>   something that should have been a bug but turns out to be a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is really a thing at all, in that the feature doesn't unexpectedly fall out of the software's design.

It's like building a radio to receive certain bands, and on one of them it picks up a station that you didn't know was there.